# Post data from aspx page to mvc page

Tags: c#

I am trying to post data from one page (aspx) to another (mvc). The way I am trying to go about it is in the code behind (aspx.cs) but so far the only way I have found to successfully redirect is to use:

```
 Response.Redirect
```

which I can't use this because it apparently can only use GET (which won't work because the data I am wanting to transfer can potentially have too many characters for GET to handle). The other stipulation is that I can't use a session variable (the person I'm working with refuses to use session data).

I've looked into things like:

```
var tdd = new TempDataDictionary();
tdd.Add("subject",subject);
```

and

```
Context.Items["subject"] = subject;
```

but I'm not sure how I'd read that data in the other mvc controller Index method.

Comment: You want to have the client redirect to a different address (same site?) and pass payload to that new address (new request)? Is that logic only known after the initial request (server side)?

Comment: I thought you could only use tempdata on mvc controller methods

Comment: You can, you simply can do an Ajax call to the other site, Query String, or simply use Rest.

Answer (score 0):

Use...

```
var data = //byte[] containing your data to post
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
request.Method = "POST";
using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    request.ContentLength = data.Length;
    requestStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}
```

This is assuming you want to programmatically POST from the code behind.

Session wouldn't work going from one web app to another. It only works from one page to another in the same site.

Comment: I will be staying within the same site, I'm just going in between pages. I'm getting confused because the page I want to send data FROM is an aspx page and the page I want to send data TO is an MVC  page, which it appears they handle things like TempData differently.

Comment: If origin and destination are both in the same site just cache the data and send the key needed to retrieve it.

Comment: How do I cache it without using a session variable? Also it appears that I can't use TempData because aspx doesn't support it? (seems like it only works for MVC controller)

Comment: Start from this article and read up about using ASP.Net caching. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa531332.aspx. Cached data is available to any ASP.Net app running on the server.